# The product of col1 and col2 directly saves values in table 2

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

table1 has 2 columns and i want to store the product values of column 1 and column 2 values from table 1 to table 2. (the product of col 1 and  col 2 directly saves values in table 2)

I'M THINKING TO ADD ONE MORE COLUMN IN TABLE 1 AND PASTE THE PRODUCT VALUES IN COL3 AND THEN PUT THE COLUMN VALUES(CLONE) IN TABLE2

Comment: What?  Please edit the question show the table definitions (as a table), sample data, expected output.  read [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need table 2 ? With virtual columns you can just do the calculation automatically in the table1.

```
koen>CREATE TABLE some_test_table (
  2    col1 NUMBER,
  3    col2 NUMBER,
  4      col3 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( col1 * col2 ) VIRTUAL
  5* );

Table SOME_TEST_TABLE created.

koen>INSERT INTO some_test_table(col1, col2) VALUES (5,9);

1 row inserted.

koen>select * from some_test_table;

   COL1    COL2    COL3 
_______ _______ _______ 
      5       9      45 

koen>
```